# Elfinder add wrong path to browse fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, elfinder

I have more than *5000* images in my uploads folder because of that *elfinder* load images very slow then I add this config to root option for speedup loading images

```
'roots' => [        [
    'driver' => 'Flysystem',
    'path' => '/',
    'URL' => $config['app_url'].'/uploads/',
    // 'URL' => '/uploa',
    'filesystem' => new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem(new \League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local('uploads')),
    'cache' => 'session', // 'session', 'memory' or false
    'accessControl' => 'Barryvdh\Elfinder\Elfinder::checkAccess',
    'autoload' => true,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            //'pattern' => '/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|docs|doc|xls|mp4|3gp|mov)$/i', //You can also set permissions for file types by adding, for example, .jpg inside pattern.
            'read'    => true,
            'write'   => true,
            'locked'  => false
        ]
    ]
]],
```

after that, my browse field doesn't work fine. it adds path without uploads word.

*before*:

```
 /uploads/Cities/test/21213.jpg
```

*after*:

```
 //Cities/test/21213.jpg
```

I test many solutions but it doesn't works. does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: What exactly did you change in your config?

Comment: How is this related to PHP after all? elFinder is a frontend library. And why should that configuration block speed something up?